# ошибка declare в MySql

Tags: mysql

[image: S]

подскажите на что жалуется здесь уже пробовал и так и сяк , все по инстуркции , никак не хочет , не понятно на что ругается.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательнее синтаксис объявления переменных. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-local-variable.html  там идет перечисление через запятую _имен переменных_ и потом уже идет тип данных. т.е.`declare id, man_id, of_id int;`

Comment: благодарю ! только на MySql столкнулся с таким страным обьявлением